# How do I apply independent HeaderStyleInterpolators in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-stack

Using react-navigation-stack 1.10.3, applying a headerTransitionPreset of 'uikit' transitioned header titles from left-to-right while fading in/out whatever elements were in headerRight or headerLeft.

With react-navigation-stack 2.0.15, this transition is deprecated in favor of using headerStyleInterpolator.forUIKit, but that transition applies universally to the entire header, not just the title.

How do I replicate the previous behavior on 1.10.X with 2.0.X where I can use forFade on headerRight and headerLeft?

Example on 2.0.15:
[image]

Example on 1.10.3:
[image]

The main issue is the removal of the fade animation when going back in the stack and it's replacement with a left-to-right transition.

Answer (score 0):

The `forUIKit` styles mimic the native iOS behavior. If you don't want the same behavior, you can use a custom style interpolator instead.

If you want to keep the same interpolator from `forUIKit`, but want to fade the left and right button instead of the default transition, you can override those styles with something like this:

```js
function forCustomHeaderAnimation(options) {
  const { progress } = options.current;
  const styles = HeaderStyleInterpolators.forUIKit(options);

  return {
    ...styles,
    leftButtonStyle: { opacity: progress },
    leftLabelStyle: {},
    rightButtonStyle: { opacity: progress },
  };
}

// ...

static navigationOptions = {
  headerStyleInterpolator: forCustomHeaderAnimation
}
```

Source: https://github.com/react-navigation/navigation-ex/blob/2243b45cc1addf83727166d82736d214f181b1fb/packages/stack/src/TransitionConfigs/HeaderStyleInterpolators.tsx

Comment: I added examples of the UIKit animation on 2.0.15 and and 1.10.3. I think the 2.0.15 may have a bug?

Comment: I just posted an example of how you can override parts of the animation. You'll need to tweak it to achieve what behavior you want.

Comment: the solution above still doesn't resolve the issue but i'll keep playing with it. thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: It looks like the actual issue here is that, even though the fade animation is still taking place on the right button, the left-to-right transition with the background color still takes place regardless https://share.getcloudapp.com/ApuOWBg1 which is what makes it look so jarring

Comment: If you also want a fade animation on the background, you can override it to use `opacity` instead of translation likeI did for left button and right button in the example.

Here is the original code for the animation. You ca override parts of it as you want https://github.com/react-navigation/navigation-ex/blob/2243b45cc1addf83727166d82736d214f181b1fb/packages/stack/src/TransitionConfigs/HeaderStyleInterpolators.tsx#L92

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I'll take a look and thanks again for taking the time to respond!